# Aprroximate graph to function

Tags: functions, approximation, graphing-functions

there is a set of points which set a graph that is not linear.
Is there any method to approximate a function that is close enough to this graph?

I've read some articles and got to know approximation using gaussianns, I'd like to know if there's another method I could use by employing only the points and not the graph they create.

Thanks in adnvace !

Comment: If you want a useful answer, you will need to supply more detail. As it stands your question is very confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [Lagrange Polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial).

Ignore this sentence, I'm just writing it because otherwise there wouldn't be enough characters on my answer for me to be allowed to post it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your use case is, but I would **not** use [Lagrange Polynomial Interpolation Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial) in this case. If you want to estimate a function, that is not what Lagrange Polynomials do. They create a unique polynomial which passes through all the points. This polynomial's degree (roughly corresponding to size and time needed to calculate) is directly dependent on the number of points ($\mathrm{degree} = \mathrm{points} - 1$).

I'm not sure what you want to do with the data result, but [Regression Analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_analysis) is probably what you want.